# In my notes app, I am not able to redirect into the same link I visited already. How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

In my notes app project I am learning by the Udemy course **The Modern JavaScript Bootcamp** by **Andrew J. Mead**, there is a project called **Notes App**.

In that project, there is a feature where I can click a link to open it's edit page. Everything is working fine but after I open the **edit.html** (the edit page) and go back to my **index.html** (main page), I am not able to open the same note edit page again. I don't think this is a problem with my browser because I have tried it in **Microsoft Edge**, **Google Chrome** and **Opera GX**. I am sending the code of my projects here.

Also I have sent a video of my problem in the form of a **mega.io** link (the file is of 200 mb)
**https://mega.nz/file/Ll0wDQ6T#pd18MwXrpYgermGITy_cu5KspFbNtiYMx3GbhYSG23Q**

**edit.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Notes Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
  <input id="note-title" placeholder="Enter Note Title シ">
  <textarea id="note-body" placeholder="Enter Note Body シ"></textarea>
  <button id="remove-note">Remove Note</button>
  <script src="notes-functions.js"></script>
  <script src="notes-edit.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Notes App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Notes App</h1>
    <h2>Take notes and never forget</h2>
    <input id="search-text" type="text" placeholder="Filter notes" />
    <select id="filter-by">
      <option value="byEdited">Sort by last edited</option>
      <option value="byCreated">Sort by recently created</option>
      <option value="alphabetical">Sort alphabetically</option>
    </select>
    <div id="notes"></div>
    <button id="create-note">Create Note</button>
    <script src="uuidv4.js"></script>
    <script src="notes-functions.js"></script>
    <script src="notes-app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**notes-edit.js**  (for the edit page and also the website is not completed)

```
const titleElement = document.querySelector("#note-title");
const bodyElement = document.querySelector("#note-body");
const removeElement = document.querySelector("#remove-note");
const noteId = location.hash.substring(1);
let notes = getSavedNotes();
let note = notes.find(function (note) {
  return note.id === noteId;
});

if (note === undefined) {
  location.assign("/index.html");
}

titleElement.value = note.title;
bodyElement.value = note.body;

titleElement.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  note.title = e.target.value;
  saveNotes(notes);
});

bodyElement.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  note.body = e.target.value;
  saveNotes(notes);
});

removeElement.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  removeNote(note.id);
  saveNotes(notes);
  location.assign("/index.html");
});

window.addEventListener('storage', function (e) {
  if (e.key === 'notes') {
    notes = JSON.parse(e.newValue)
  }
})
```

**notes-app.js**  (for the index.html page)

```
const notes = getSavedNotes();

const filters = {
  searchText: "",
};

renderNotes(notes, filters);

document.querySelector("#create-note").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  const id = uuidv4();

  notes.push({
    id: id,
    title: "",
    body: "",
  });
  saveNotes(notes);
  location.assign(`/edit.html#${id}`);
});

document.querySelector("#search-text").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  filters.searchText = e.target.value;
  renderNotes(notes, filters);
});

document.querySelector("#filter-by").addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

**notes-functions.js**  (for the functions used in notes-app.js and notes-edit.js)

```
// Read Existing Notes From localStorage
const getSavedNotes = function () {
  const notesJSON = localStorage.getItem("notes");

  if (notesJSON !== null) {
    return JSON.parse(notesJSON);
  } else {
    return [];
  }
};

// Save The Notes To localStorage
const saveNotes = function (notes) {
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes));
};

// Remove a note
const removeNote = function (id) {
  const noteIndex = notes.findIndex(function (note) {
    return note.id === id;
  });

  if (noteIndex > -1) {
    notes.splice(noteIndex, 1);
  }
};

// Generate the DOM structure for a note
const generateNoteDOM = function (note) {
  const noteEl = document.createElement("div");
  const textEl = document.createElement("a");
  const button = document.createElement("button");

  // Config the remove note btn
  button.textContent = "❌";
  noteEl.appendChild(button);
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    removeNote(note.id);
    saveNotes(notes);
    renderNotes(notes, filters);
  });

  // Setup the note title text
  if (note.title.length > 0) {
    textEl.textContent = note.title;
  } else {
    textEl.setAttribute("href", `/edit.html#${note.id}`);
    textEl.textContent = "Unnamed Note";
  }

  noteEl.appendChild(textEl);

  return noteEl;
};

// Render (application) notes
const renderNotes = function (notes, filters) {
  const filteredNotes = notes.filter(function (note) {
    return note.title.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase());
  });

  document.querySelector("#notes").innerHTML = "";

  filteredNotes.forEach(function (note) {
    const noteEl = generateNoteDOM(note);
    document.querySelector("#notes").appendChild(noteEl);
  });
};
```

Any answer would be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll have a higher chance of getting a complete and relevant answer if you do some debugging first yourself, and if you trim down the relevant code to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) needed for somebody else to help, rather than posting all of your code. I'd start with investigating your event listeners - are you sure they are being assigned correctly on each page load? Are they firing correctly (or rather, responding to the event correctly) when the button is clicked?

Comment: I don't see any functionality in your JS related to "clicking on the note title should take me to its edit page". Is that what you're trying to implement? Or are you saying this is already implemented (where?) and it's not working? Edit: oh, I see in `generateNoteDOM `. When you inspect your HTML, what does it show? Does it have something like `<a href="/edit.html#1234">sample</a>`?

Comment: yes, the index html page has a link to the edit page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're only setting the `href` attribute if the length is 0:

```
// Setup the note title text
if (note.title.length > 0) {
  textEl.textContent = note.title;
} else {
  textEl.setAttribute("href", `/edit.html#${note.id}`);
  textEl.textContent = "Unnamed Note";
}
```

So you just need to set the `href` regardless of the title, and then it should be a clickable link:

```
// Setup the note title text
if (note.title.length > 0) {
  textEl.textContent = note.title;
} else {
  textEl.textContent = "Unnamed Note";
}

// set the note link
textEl.setAttribute("href", `/edit.html#${note.id}`);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Much appreciated